# Can i get the follower of a certain user in a string Array

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

I want to get the follower of a certain user in a `string[]` so I can add them with my bot.

```
private static TwitterService tservice;
...

tservice.ListFollowerIdsOf(new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions());
```

This method sounds like it could give you a list of ids of specific twitter follower i tried but it did not work that well.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it looks like you need to specify a followerId in the `ListFollowerIdsOfOptions()` object

> {ScreenName = _hero}

```
var service = GetAuthenticatedService();
var followers = service.ListFollowerIdsOf(new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions(){ScreenName = _hero});
```

Comment: thanks it worked  i forgot to do {ScreenName = NAME});

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark the answer as the right one thanks.